# Is FlinkKafkaConsumer setStartFromLatest() method needed when we use auto.offset.reset=latest kafka properties

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

In my flink application I have kafka datasource. I am using kafka property `auto.offset.reset=latest`. I am wondering if I need to use `FlinkKafkaConsumer.setStartFromLatest()`. Are they similar? Can I use either of them? Following is the documentation from flink code. But it is not clear how this method is related to the kafka property.

```
/**
 * Specifies the consumer to start reading from the latest offset for all partitions. This lets
 * the consumer ignore any committed group offsets in Zookeeper / Kafka brokers.
 *
 * <p>This method does not affect where partitions are read from when the consumer is restored
 * from a checkpoint or savepoint. When the consumer is restored from a checkpoint or savepoint,
 * only the offsets in the restored state will be used.
 *
 * @return The consumer object, to allow function chaining.
 */
public FlinkKafkaConsumerBase<T> setStartFromLatest() {
    this.startupMode = StartupMode.LATEST;
    this.startupOffsetsTimestamp = null;
    this.specificStartupOffsets = null;
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to put `auto.offset.reset=latest` in the property map if `setStartFromLatest()` is called.

Internally, Flink uses Kafka consumer client's `assign` method to manage partition assignment to Flinks tasks. It uses the value of `startupMode` to initialise Kafka consumer. `startupMode` is set through `setStartFrom...` methods, and default value is `GROUP_OFFSETS`.

Have to put `consumer group id` into property if using `FlinkKafkaConsumer`. Another choice is to use `KafkaSouce.builder()`([sample code](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/#kafka-source)), which provides functions to set those things up.